# Email sent using contact form displays admins "from" address, and not the visitors email

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-contact-form

This page uses Drupals contact form to send emails: http://www.westlake.school.nz/contact

Problem is, the school staff use outlook. When they recieve email from parents etc, the email comes in as

> "From: admin@example.com On Behalf Of
>   Westlake Boys High School"

In Gmail it comes in correctly such as

> from  Westlake Boys High School
>   parentsEmailAddress@yahoo.com

Unfortunately, I cannot tell the entire school staff to stop using Outlook and exchange.

Can Drupals drupal_mail function be altered in order to fix this?

From contact.pages.inc:

```
drupal_mail('contact', 'page_mail', $contact['recipients'], language_default(), $values, $from);
```

Comment: [__A DETAILED SOLUTION CAN BE FOUND HERE__](http://www.fosspedia.com/drupal-remove-on-behalf-of-from-the-sent-mails).

Comment: ^link dead. A detailed answer would have fared better

Comment: [Corrected link](https://web.archive.org/web/20130103155925/http://www.fosspedia.com/drupal-remove-on-behalf-of-from-the-sent-mails), using the Wayback Machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmsimont explains on this URL (http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_mail#comment-3243) that

> the $from parameter will only alter the
>   From header, not the Sender, Errors-to
>   or Return-Path.

of the drupal_mail function that is used by contact_mail_page_submit.

with more details (code from the `drupal_mail()` function)

```
line 3 - $default_from = variable_get('site_mail', ini_get('sendmail_from'));

line 9 -     'from'     => isset($from) ? $from : $default_from,

line 23 -  if ($default_from) {
line 24 -    // To prevent e-mail from looking like spam, the addresses in the Sender and
line 25 -    // Return-Path headers should have a domain authorized to use the originating
line 26 -    // SMTP server. Errors-To is redundant, but shouldn't hurt.
line 27 -    $headers['From'] = $headers['Sender'] = $headers['Return-Path'] = $headers['Errors-To'] = $default_from;
line 28 -  }
line 29 -  if ($from) {
line 30 -    $headers['From'] = $from;
line 31 -  }
line 32 -  $message['headers'] = $headers;
```

So to solve your problem you could implement hook_mail function (http://drupal.org/node/358855#comment-2079266)

More resources can be found here:

1 - http://drupal.org/node/656472

2 - http://drupal.org/node/861562

3 - http://www.nmglc.co.uk/content/overriding-drupals-mail-function

Comment: Thank you, this is much further information than what I found.

Comment: gbhall, Great ! If you found that this answer solved your problem, mark it as correct. Thanks !